# Заменить окончания слов с 'ed' на 'ing'

Tags: c#, редактор-текста

Необходимо заменить окончания всех слов в предложении с *ed* на *ing*.
Как найти эти слова в строке?

Comment: поиском? регулярным выражением? где вы это хотите сделать? в студии? или вызвать код который получит строку и ее изменит?

Comment: Делаю в visual studio. Реализовал занос всех слов строки в массив. Сейчас думаю как отделить окончания

Comment: так что все-таки нужно? просто две буквы с конца заменить? или произвести разбор и по результату что-то поменять?

Comment: Если в слове две последние буквы 'ed' их необходимо заменить на 'ing'

Comment: например: [RegExp.Replace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/xwewhkd1(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: `tried` -> `trying`

Comment: @Igor: `wed` -> `wing`

Comment: `bed` -> `bing` - так и завоевывает популярность поисковик от Microsoft )) По грамматическим правилам тут надо, если по хорошему, а не вот так вот.

Comment: Нужно именно так) Никакая грамматика не интересует

Answer (score 1):

> Если в слове две последние буквы 'ed' их необходимо заменить на 'ing'

Если прямо в лоб, как то так можно.

```
public string[] ReplaceArrayWords(string[] array, string first, string last){
List<string> result = new List<string>();

    foreach(string word in array){
        if(word.Substring(word.length-first.length,first.length).Equals(first))
            result.Add(word.Substring(0,word.length-first.length)+last);
        else
            result.Add(word);
    }

return result.ToArray();
}
```

c Framework 4.5+ (по предложению **Alexander Petrov**)

```
public string[] ReplaceArrayWords(string[] array, string first, string last){
List<string> result = new List<string>();

    foreach(string word in array){
        if(word.EndsWith(first))
            result.Add(word.Substring(0,word.length-first.length)+last);
        else
            result.Add(word);
    }

return result.ToArray();
}
```

потом:

```
string[] newArray = ReplaceArrayWords(array,"ed","ing");
```

Comment: Ваш код можно упростить, используя [String.EndsWith](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.string.endswith%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Спасибо, не знал подобного метода, ещё в 4.5 версии появился))

Comment: Метод появился в версии 3.5. На странице MSDN щелкните на "Другие версии" и увидите все версии, где данные метод реализован.

Answer (score 1):

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
string[] words;
for (int i = 0; i < words.Length; i++)
{
    words[i] = Regex.Replace(words[i], "(ed)$", "ing");
}
```

Comment: Это не совсем то, о чем спрашивал Дмитрий. Слова не в массиве, а в строке.

Comment: Он же сказал, что "Реализовал занос всех слов строки в массив."

Comment: а, действительно.